# git with two authoritative locals, one remote Github

Tags: git, github

Maybe I don't know how to ask the question, but I can't seem to find the answer -- I'm sure that this must be a common situation.

I have a development desktop using git, and a Github repository, and all is well and good. I now have a need to develop remotely from my desktop using a laptop, and I want to synchronize my development desktop with my traveling laptop, using Github as a transfer medium, with one user account. In other words, I want to have both machines pointing to the same remote repository on Github using the same Github credentials (username and password).

I know I can clone the remote repository on the laptop.

Will Github give me static if I then try to push edits using the same account?
Will 'git pull' synchronize the lagging machine?
How does Github deal with one user account shared across multiple machines?

Does Github think that different IP addresses are two different users, even if the login credentials are identical?

Comment: Have you tried it? As you said, this is very common. The out-of-the-box experience should be close to what you want.

Comment: Very close. Exact, even. "Yes. Github cares about user credentials, IP addresses aren't credentiials. No."

Answer (score 3):

> Does Github think that different IP addresses are two different users, even if the login credentials are identical?

No, you can push from any machine/IP, using the same credentials.

You can [review your security log](https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-your-security-log/) for your account: it will list the last 50 actions or those performed within the last 90 days, and its IP address each action originated.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/settings/user_security_history_action.png]

Comment: Thank you. My new laptop is on the way, so I can't try this now, hence the prospective nature of my question. Is this the workflow? (1) edit on machine A. (2) add, commit, and push from machine A. (3) pull to machine B. (4) edit on machine B. (5) add, commit, and push from machine B. (6) pull to machine A. (7) repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite ready to declare that this is a complete and authoritative answer, but it took very little effort to 'transfer' my work from my old workstation to my new workstation. Git and Github experts may (or may not) cringe, but this series of commands worked for me, and I've used this for about a dozen remote repositories. YMMV.

ON THE NEW COMPUTER, RUN THIS SERIES OF COMMANDS:

```
mkdir OldRepoName
cd .\OldRepoName\
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/ccc31807/OldRepoName
git remote -v
git pull origin master
```

From this point, I am able to work, edit files, add new files, commit, and push the changes up to origin, so (at this point) everything seems to work okay. I'm still keeping my old computer around, just in case. ;-)

CC.